# Short cut keys in java

Tags: java

How can I write programs for shortcut keys in java.  For Example, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> means the save option should work.  Can anyone help?

Comment: This would be entirely dependent on what GUI layer you're using.  Which one *are* you using?

Comment: If they don't know what they are using, they are usually using Swing :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're need to set mnemonics for appropriate buttons. Also you can set some accelerators for menu items. [Here is a rather good example.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JButtonsetMnemonicKeyEventVKA.htm)

Comment: +1, using accelerators on a menu item is a great way to do this. When the accelerator is set the key binding is created automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to read the Java tutorial for
[Key Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: Note that key events are low-level and sometimes using them may cause repeating events.

Comment: Swing was designed to use Key Bindings, so I would not recommend this approach. Although the Java tutorial also has a section on using Key Bindings that should be read.

Answer (score 0):

Swing was designed to use [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for this type of functionality. You create an Action and map a KeyStroke to invoke this Action. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an Action](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on Mac OS X, use accelerators instead of mnenomics, which are not suppported under the native look and feel [Apple Java development guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/Java14Development.pdf)